# PHP Form not working like last week

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, upgrade

My hosting supplier just upgraded PHP from 5.3 to 5.4 so I'm not sure whether this has affected any forms on my website because it was working last week fine.

This is my form

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">

<label for="artist">1. Artist Name: </label><input id="artist" name="artist" type="text" />

<label for="song">2. Song Name: </label><input id="song" name="song" type="text" />

<label for="label">3. Label: </label><input id="label" name="label" type="text" />

<label for="genre">4. Genre: </label>
<select name="genre"><option value="RnB">RnB</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Hip Hop">Hip Hop</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Reggae">Reggae</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Gospel">Gospel</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Dance">Dance</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Jazz">Jazz</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Afrobeats">Afrobeats</option></select>
<select name="genre"><option value="Soul">Soul</option></select>

<label for="genre">5. Country/Area: </label>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Country"><option value="UK">UK</option>  </optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Country"><option value="US">US</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Country"><option value="CANADA">CANADA</option> </optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Country"><option value="JAMAICA">JAMAICA</option></optgroup></select>

<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="CARIBBEAN">CARIBBEAN</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="S.AMERICA">S.AMERICA</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="AFRICA">AFRICA</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="EUROPE">EUROPE</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="AUS">AUS</option></optgroup></select>
<select name="country"><optgroup label="Area"><option value="ASIA">ASIA</option></optgroup></select>

<label for="songlink">6. Song Link (Youtube Only): </label><input id="songlink" name="songlink" size="50" type="text" />

<label for="artistphoto">7. Artist Photo Link (Square): </label><input id="artistphoto" name="photolink" size="35" type="text" />

<label for="email">8. Email Address: </label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" />

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

This is the bulk of my my insert.php file

```
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$Artist=$_POST['artist'];
$Song=$_POST['song'];
$Label=$_POST['label'];
$Genre=$_POST['genre'];
$Country=$_POST['country'];
$SongLink=$_POST['songlink'];
$PhotoLink=$_POST['photolink'];
$Email=$_POST['email'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(artistname, songname, label, genre, country, songlink, photolink, email)VALUES('$artist','$song','$label','$genre','$country','$songlink','$photolink','$email')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

When I submit the form now it shows up empty in my sql database.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` chances are `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. It might have something to do with it, but that's almost a slim chance. Worth trying out though.

Comment: By the way, I don't know why you're repeating `<select name="genre">` and the others, you only need it once. It's the values that matter.

Comment: Another thing. Your POST variables don't match your VALUES. For example: `$Artist=$_POST['artist'];` and `'$artist'` those variables are case-sensitive. That needs to be changed to `'$Artist'` and do the same for the others.

Comment: Hi Fred I think the update put that in my code as the output was all over the place, I took the repeating code out as you said and it shows up as expected but still not recording any values in the database.

Comment: See my above just above yours. That will explain it.

Comment: Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Your POST variables' letter-cases do not match your values.

```
$Artist=$_POST['artist'];
$Song=$_POST['song'];
$Label=$_POST['label'];
$Genre=$_POST['genre'];
$Country=$_POST['country'];
$SongLink=$_POST['songlink'];
$PhotoLink=$_POST['photolink'];
$Email=$_POST['email'];
```

and your VALUES

```
('$artist','$song','$label','$genre','$country','$songlink','$photolink','$email')
```

doesn't match. They're case-sensitive.

Change it to:

```
('$Artist','$Song','$Label','$Genre','$Country','$SongLink','$PhotoLink','$Email')
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

`error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);` when in development.

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: Wow, one upvote and one downvote (*I'm so fortunate*). Thank you to all :) here's lookin' at you kid ;-)

Comment: Plus, a very special thanks to the downvoter. I always loved a good mystery (grin)

Comment: @Darren Thanks Darren. I've learned to take it with a grain of salt, along with a dash of humour ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think all answers need more than a dash of humour ;)

Comment: @Darren It certainly eleviates the pressure. Some are just a little too uptight for my taste (grin) I can't help it, I just need humour in my life.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Provided its the dry, snarky sense of humour; I'm all in! :D

Comment: @Darren ...and nothin' but ;-)